# Remove Bitnami Jenkins Access page

Tags: jenkins, bitnami

I have bitnami jenkins installed.
I have no problem with the url `http://yourhost/jenkins` but i need to delete the Bitnami Welcome page. is any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation (https://wiki.bitnami.com/Components/Bitnami_info_page) says that the bnconfig tool should be used. However for me this doesn't work and I changed it manually in the apache configuration files.
To do so, change in file  /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf the lines:

```text
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
  DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs"
```

and

```text
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
  DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs"
```

into:

```text
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
  DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/htdocs"
```

and

```text
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
  DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/htdocs"
```

Then restart apache:

sudo  /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache

This si brutal but it works, and the vhost (http://yourhost/jenkins should also work) :)

Note that the main documentation (https://wiki.bitnami.com/Native_Installers_Quick_Start_Guide) says in part "How to change the default page that appears when accessing the installation?" that changing it manually is the way to go, but suggest to use a modified version of the main page. I guess this is fine if you have several apps installed.